# Number of congruence classes

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have a function $f: \mathbb{Z}/6 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/6$ where $\mathbb{Z}/6=$ collection of congruence classes modulo 6 defined as $ [a] =[a^2+1]$. I want to find the Image of this function. I did that by calculating for $[a]$s for for first $10$ $a$s. How do I do this without actually putting values for $a$.

Comment: You don't need to put it for the first $10$ $a$s, you need to take $a = 1,2,3,4,5,6$. Infact, you can reduce this to $a=1,2,3$ because $[(6-a)^2 + 1] = [a^2+1]$, so you need to check only these three values. That gives you $[a^2 + 1] \in \{ 2,5,4\}$.

Comment: You should only need to do it for a=0,1,2,3,4,5 since 6 is congruent to 0(modulo 6). So the range should be {1,2,5,4}... I think he just made a mistake.